# double quot in string via JSON and asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

return string in json format via webform , `"` will be escaped correctly and all works good , but in mvc `"` will be show in `\"` format , so josn format will be corrupted

this code is in mvc that return `"name\":\"MSLM"`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   string s = @"name"":""MSLM";
   return Json(s, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

this code is in webform works correctly and return `"name":"MSLM"`

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Charset = "utf8";
Response.ContentType = "application/json";
string s = @"name"":""MSLM";
Response.Write(s);
Response.End();
```

string tested via serialization via this code but not works too

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string s = "\"asdfasdf\":\"asdfad\"";
return js.Serialize(s);
```

Comment: But when you assign string s = @"name"":""MSLM"; s is actually name":"MSLM, I think you should write string s = @"""name"":""MSLM""";

Answer (score 1):

Your first example, where you say the output is correct, is not correct.

```
string s = @"name"":""MSLM";
```

This translates to the string `name":"MSLM`

Note that I did not use quotes to delimit the string. Just like the string `foo` can be typed as "foo", `name":"MSLM` can be noted as "name":"MSLM".

Your second example, however, seemd to be exactly what you want.

```
string s = "\"asdfasdf\":\"asdfad\"";
```

This translates to the string `"asdfasdf":"asdfad"`. Which can be written as ""asdfasdf":"asdfad"". **Look at the double quotes at the start and end**. The outer set of quotes denote where your string `s` stops. The inner set of quotes are used to wrap around the `asdfasdf` values.

The second example could also be phrased as the following:

```
string s = @"""asdfasdf"":""asdfad""";
```

These two snippets are equivalent. Using the `@"mystring"` notation is usually used for scenarios where you want to enter multi-line string variables, but can be used on a single line as well (I don't see why you'd use it, but it is valid).

Long story short, example 2 is correct, example 1 isn't. I suspect you've made an error during testing, hence the confusion.